# Upper bound on integer coordinates on a function graph

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, convex-analysis, convexity-inequality

Let $n\geq 2$ and $f\in \mathcal{C}^2([|1,n|],\mathbb{R})$ such that $|f’|$ has a maximum strictly less than $1$ and $f’’$ has a minimum strictly positive.
Show that the number of integer coordinates in the graph of $f$ is at most $1+2n^{\frac{2}{3}}$

This exercise appears in a worksheet and despite drawing various things, i can’t figure out how to prove it. Maybe by induction on $n$ but we might need assumptions on $f(n)$ and $f’(n)$…

Comment: what does the $[|1,n|]$ notation mean?

Comment: It is not an induction problem. The key is that the conditions on $f'$ and $f''$ restrict how fast $f$ can move from one integer to the next. Because $|f'| < 1$, the function cannot move from $(k, m)$ to $(k+1, m\pm 1)$. To change in value by $1$, the $x$ coordinate has to change by more than $1$. And because of the $f''$ condition, if $f$ requires $\Delta x$ to increase by $1$ in value at one point, from then on it must change take less than $\Delta x$ to increase by $1$. It can also have at most one turning point, and similar remarks apply to decreasing by $1$.